# Use underscore to find a value by key

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a string that I need to search for within a json object and return back a specific hash number from that found value. I got it to work without underscore, but it's poorly optimized. What I need to do is stop the loop as soon as the `fileToSearch` string is found.

For example, I have a json object here:

```
  var json = {
    "images/mike.jpg" : "images/mike.12345.jpg",
    "images/joe.jpg" : "images/joe.axcvas.jpg",
    "images/mary.jpg" : "images/mary.mndfkndf.jpg",
    "images/jane.jpg" : "images/jane.dfad34.jpg",
  };
```

And I have a variable `fileToSearch` that I need to look for in the above object.

```
 var fileToSearch = "joe.jpg";
```

**What should get outputted is the hash value in `images/joe.axcvas.jpg`, so `axcvas`.**

Without underscore:

```
  var hash;

  for (var key in json) {
    var index = key.indexOf(fileToSearch);
    if (index !== -1) {
      hash = json[key].split('.')[1];
    }
  }
  console.log(hash); //axcvas
```

How can I optimize/achieve this with Underscore?

Comment: Heck, you don't even need `filter`. Just throw a `break` in after you find your hash and it's pretty optimal already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`_.findKey`](http://underscorejs.org/#findKey) in such way:

```
var key = _.findKey(json, function(value, key) {
    return key.indexOf(fileToSearch) >= 0;
});
var hash = key? json[key].split('.')[1] : undefined;
```

Note that this method is available since v1.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the loop when you find the element

```
 var hash;

 for (var key in json) {
     var index = key.indexOf(fileToSearch);
     if (index !== -1) {
       hash = json[key].split('.')[1];
       break;
     }
 }
 console.log(hash);
```